# Set padding to an element when reload with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I succeed to set the padding top of an element from the height of two others, i think all it's ok except when i resize my page, i need to reload it to retrieve the correct padding value.

Here's my JQuery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

marge = ($(".items").height() - ($(".picture").outerHeight()*.4))

function resizeBottom() {
    $("div.bottom").css("padding-top", marge + "px" );
};
resizeBottom();

onResize = function() { $("div.bottom").css("padding-top", marge + "px" ); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate the `marge` value on the resize handler

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    onResize = function () {
        var marge = ($(".items").height() - ($(".picture").outerHeight() * .4))
        $("div.bottom").css("padding-top", marge + "px");
    }
    onResize()
});
```

I hope that the method `onResize` is added as a resize event handler for the `window` object

Another way to write it is

```
//register the window resize handler
$(window).resize(function () {
    var marge = ($(".items").height() - ($(".picture").outerHeight() * .4))
    $("div.bottom").css("padding-top", marge + "px");
}).resize()
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull answer,the second solution works but not every times, it's really strange. I continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's a job of the event handler, ".resize()". Check this page for details. I hope this is what you are looking for. http://api.jquery.com/resize/